# postfix and iRedMail- Relaying Denied

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to setup iRedMail and am way over my head here.
I have installed it, and can send emails internally, but not externally.
When I send an email from outside, I get the following return email:

```
The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.7.1    
<test@mailtest.domain.com.au>... Relaying denied (state 13).
```

Now I have no idea where to start looking! Any ideas?
I have really only just installed iRedMail so I am unsure what else I need to do to get it working.
I've pointed my MX records to that server, so that shouldnt be the problem.

Also- if i stop postfix (so nothing is listening on port 25) and send a test email, I get the same reply back. Why would I get the same reply back even if postfix is stopped? I have run tcpdump over 25 and can see the packets coming in/out, so its definitely a configuration issue!

I suppose my question is not really "what is my problem", but more "What configuration needs to be completed on postfix and iRedMail?"

Comment: How you are sending this mails, with roundcube or some external client (Mozilla or Outlook)

Comment: Sending through roundcube works, but sending from anything other than interally (so i am sending from my outlook and google apps for example) returns the error

Answer (score 1):

So it is fixed, and it is quite a noobish mistake!

I should have twigged when i was getting the same error, even if port 25 was not open.
Turns out.. I had an iptables rule in their that was forwarding to another server. So the relaying denied message I was getting was not even from the server i thought it was! Removing this rule has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have misconfigured your client. Problem is with authenticating user for outgoing server (smtp). You must enable it to send emails correctly.